# retrofit using more than one variable in @path

Tags: android, http, url, retrofit

i'm trying to send a request using multiple variables in the url like the following code

```
@GET("rides/getride/{user}/{lat_orig}%2C{lon_orig}/{lat_dest}%2C{lon_dest}/")
        Call<User> getride(@Path("user") String user,@Path("lat_orig") double lat_orig,@Path("long_orig") double lon_orig,
                @Path("lat_dest") double lat_dest,@Path("lon_dest") double lon_dest);
```

but its throwing me an error. is there another way to do it? 
do i ahve to enter one by one and then send it all together?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message can really help guide to what is wrong.  There error you are getting is --

> URL "rides/getride/{user}/{lat_orig}%2C{lon_orig}/{lat_dest}%2C{lon_dest}/" does not contain "{long_orig}". (parameter #3)

From that, we can see that the issue is in your url you have "lon_orig" (no g) and in your `Path` annotation you have -- "long_orig" (with a g).  Change one or the other so they match.